# fwrite, fread - problems with fread

Tags: c++, c, structure, fwrite, fread

I have following code:

```
int main()
{
    char* pedal[20];
    char* pedal2[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        pedal[i] = "Pedal";
    }
    FILE* plik;
    plik = fopen("teraz.txt","wb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       fwrite(pedal[i],strlen(pedal[i]),1,plik);
    }
    system("pause");
    fclose(plik);
    plik = fopen("teraz.txt","rb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        fread(pedal2[i],5,1,plik); //I know for now that every element has 5 bytes
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pedal2[i] << std::endl;
    }
    fclose(plik);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It's crashing at reading and second question let's assume that I have structure where I keep like integers, floats and also char* array and how can I easly write whole structure to the file? Normal fwrite with sizeof structure is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that you didn't allocate buffer for reading. In fact line

```
fread(pedal2[i],5,1,plik)
```

reads to unknown place. You need allocate memory (in your case it is 5 + 1 bytes for zero terminated string).

```
pedal2[i] = malloc(5+1);
fread(pedal2[i],5,1,plik)
```

Don't forget to release it after usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read into `pedal2` without first having allocated space for it.

You need something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    pedal[i] = malloc(100); //allocate some space
}
```

Comment: Even if it set as 20 in advance? Well i guess malloc hre I come. And what about that structure?

Comment: no, you allocating an array of 20 pointers on the stack, but you aren't allocating the very same pointers' value.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question seem to have already been answered by Simone & Dewfy.

For your second question about how to write structure values into the file, you will have to write member by member.

Please check [fprintf](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html). You can probably use it for writing different data types.